# C# Replacing text in .docx and download the changes

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, ms-word

On my web server I have docx files. I wish to open one, make changes, then return that changed in memory "file" to be downloaded from a web api method. I do not wish to save the changes to disk.

I have 2 methods, 1 being a test to just see if downloading the file works. PrintForm2() is the test and it just downloads a file on disk and that works fine. **PrintForm() however, actually ends up getting called twice automatically and chrome console shows and ERR_CONNECTION_RESET error. I have no clue why that is.**

**So the 2 part question is, does anyone know how I can open a template, make some changes, and return those changes to be downloaded without saving said changes to disk and returning that saved file?**

This is not in Core. It's .NET 4.6.1

```
private HttpResponseMessage PrintForm2()
        {
            string templateFolderPath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Templates");

            string filePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(templateFolderPath, "Daily.docx");

            HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);

            byte[] fileBtyes = File.ReadAllBytes(filePath);

            response.Content = new StreamContent(new MemoryStream(fileBtyes));

            response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document");
            response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new System.Net.Http.Headers.ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment")
            {
                FileName = "Daily.docx"
            };

            return response;
        }

        private HttpResponseMessage PrintForm(string docName, string bondId, bool useHisHerShe)
        {
            var templatesPath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Templates");
            var filePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(templatesPath, docName);

            using (MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                // using the memory stream create a word processing object
                using (WordprocessingDocument bondDoc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(filePath, true))
                {
                    // get the main document part and replace the text we need to replace
                    var mainPart = bondDoc.MainDocumentPart;

                    string docText;
                    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(mainPart.GetStream()))
                    {
                        docText = sr.ReadToEnd();
                    }

                    string pattern = @"\{BondType\}";
                    string replacement = "Testing";
                    string updatedDocText = Regex.Replace(docText, pattern, replacement);

                    // add back in the updated contents
                    using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(mainPart.GetStream(FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write)))
                    {
                        sw.Write(updatedDocText);
                    }

                    //bondDoc.Clone(System.IO.Path.Combine(templatesPath, "00-Daily.docx"));
                }

                // copy the modified docx content to the memory stream
                memStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open))
                {
                    fs.CopyTo(memStream);
                }

                var response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);

                response.Content = new StreamContent(memStream);
                response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new System.Net.Http.Headers.ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment")
                {
                    FileName = docName
                };
                response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document");

                return response;
            }
        }
```

Comment: I expect you could do this with the OpenXML SDK. But you probably will need to get into some level of detail of the OpenXML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone is interested I figured it out.

```
private HttpResponseMessage PrintForm3(string docName, string bondId, bool useHisHerShe)
    {
        try
        {
            var templatesPath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Templates");
            var filePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(templatesPath, docName);

            MemoryStream originalStream = new MemoryStream(File.ReadAllBytes(filePath));

            using(WordprocessingDocument doc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(originalStream, true))
            {
                MainDocumentPart mainPart = doc.MainDocumentPart;

                StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(mainPart.GetStream());

                string docText = streamReader.ReadToEnd();

                string pattern = @"\{BondType\}";
                string replacement = "Testing";
                string updatedDocText = Regex.Replace(docText, pattern, replacement);

                StreamWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter(mainPart.GetStream(FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write));
                streamWriter.Write(updatedDocText);
                streamWriter.Flush();
            }

            var response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);

            response.Content = new ByteArrayContent(originalStream.ToArray());
            response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new System.Net.Http.Headers.ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment")
            {
                FileName = docName
            };
            response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document");

            return response;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
```